# Resize and Rotate Rectangle by using its line touch event

Tags: android, canvas, image-resizing, touch-event, scaletransform

Move rectangle on finger touch event and also Resize rectangle by moving it left ,right, top or bottom line finger touch and rotate it when I touch or move on bottom right corner of the rectangle(show in figure) and redraw it (canvas) android please help if anyone can.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have all in a child class from [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) you could override

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final Point point = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            press(point);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drag(point);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            release(point);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the method `press(Point point)` you need to identify with `point to point` or `point to line` distance which feature is the most near to be selected. And the method `drag(Point point)` helps you to drag the rect.

**Drawing**

Drawing should take place in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method but the instantiation should be outside this method. So you create the [Rect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) in your constructor or so

```
Rect rect = new rect(10, 10, 100, 100)
```

**Resize**

When you try to resize you don't need to create a new Rect you'll just use

`rect.set(x, y, dx, dy)`

**Rotate**

When you want to rotate you need to rotate the [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) then draw and afterwards rotate back to draw something else.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
canvas.restore();
```